# open multiple excel files with tkfiledialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some excel files and I want to open them at the same time and print their content. How can I do that with using tkFileDialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of how to open many (text) files and print them:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x150')
root.title('Filemenu test')

file_list = filedialog.askopenfilenames()

for file in file_list:
    with open(file) as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        print(text)
```

The Open file dialog will allow you to select from the file list with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

To open and parse Excel files I recommend you have a look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).